# Check if array contains child array and merge in parent array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do :

1. Check if array contains array.
2. If parent array contains child array then interchange the key and value of child array.
3. Update all keys of child array to '1'. i.e. value of child array after interchange key and value
4. Delete child array and merge its element to parent array.

   Example:

### Generated array:

```
 array
   'first_name' => string 'sushil' (length=6)
   'last_name' => string 'asfasfaf' (length=8)
   'gen' => string 'Male' (length=4)
   'language' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
   'biodata' => string 'sfsafsaf hdffd ' (length=15)
   'hobbies' => 
    array
       0 => string 'gaming' (length=6)
       1 => string 'football' (length=8)
       2 => string 'cricket' (length=7)
   'academic_qualification' => string 'Bachelor' (length=8)
```

I want to modify as above step:

```
 //finds if child array exists. If exists interchange key and value and update value to '1'.
 array
  'gaming' => int 1
  'football' => int 1
  'cricket' => int 1
```

And finally unset original child array and merge modified child array's element to parent array.
My expected array form:

```
 array
   'first_name' => string 'sushil' (length=6)
   'last_name' => string 'asfasfaf' (length=8)
   'gen' => string 'Male' (length=4)
   'language' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
   'biodata' => string 'sfsafsaf hdffd ' (length=15)
   'academic_qualification' => string 'Bachelor' (length=8)
   'gaming' => int 1
   'football' => int 1
   'cricket' => int 1
```

I tried like following  but its not working:

```
 $submited_data = $_POST;
         var_dump($submited_data);
         foreach($submited_data as $value){  
            if(is_array($value)) {        //checks if array contains array.
                $a = array_flip($value);  //then interchange
                var_dump($a);
                foreach($a as $key=>$b){
                    $a[$key] = 1;         //update all value to '1'.      
                }
                array_push($submited_data,$a);    // here is the problem I cannot proceed to furthur step. Please help me. How to merge modified child array to parent array.
                var_dump($a);
                
            }
        }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive just rewritten your code a bit. Please tell me if anything goes wrong!

```
<?php
    $submited_data = $_POST;
    foreach($submited_data as $key => $data)
    {
        if(is_array($data))
        {
            foreach($data as $sub_data)
            {
                $submited_data[$sub_data] = 1; 
            }
            unset($submitted_data[$key]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No problem. Would you mind marking this answer as solved (the green tick next to my answer) then? It could help others to find the answer faster later

Comment: Done. +1 for shortcut method.

Answer (score 0):

suppose `$array` is the array with child array,

```
$mergedArray = [];

array_walk_recursive($array, function($a,$b) use (&$mergedArray) { $mergedArray[$b] = $a; }); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($mergedArray);
echo '</pre>';
```